# What is happening if code is wrapped in curly braces within a function?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C and have noticed in code I've read that sometimes a block of code will be wrapped in curly braces inside of a function.

What does this do?

For example ...

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {    

  // Load config, available via macro CONFIG
  {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"config" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    self.config = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: data
                                                            options: NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                             format: nil
                                                              error: nil];
    [data release];
  }

  // snip

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a way of limiting the scope of the variables declared in the block.  In your example path and data will not be visible outside of the curly braces.

Answer (score 10):

That's called "scope"...

Variables declared inside the braces only exists inside the braces.

Imagine the following:

```
int main( void )
{
  int my_var = 3;
  {
     int my_var = 5;
     printf( "my_var=%d\n", my_var );
  }

  printf( "my_var=%d\n", my_var );

  exit( 0 );
}
```

This will print:

```
my_var=5
my_var=3
```

Comment: Good one Macmade. One more thing, scope is not specific to objective C, it is present in C as well.